# Pandas, Group datetime64 by minute

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Series object with a few thousand datetime64's in it.

Each datetime64 has date, hour, minute, second.

I would like to extract the data into an object that only contains the HHMM portion of the datetime, and then do a value count.

How do I do that?